# не могу вытянуть селектор с определенным классом

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

не работает this, тело функции должно ссылаться на селектор с классом .sl_item к которому добавился класс active. Задача состоит в том что, при активном слайде в слайдере, определенный таб был открыт.

```
if($('a.sl_item').hasClass('active')){
        var id = $( this).attr("href");
        $(id).addClass("tab_active").siblings(".tab").removeClass("tab_active");
    }
```

Comment: что-то мне подсказывает, что вы надеятесь что `this` будет указывать на `a,sl_item` который вы только что проверили. Но честно сказать не понятно, с чего вы так думаете. По данному фрагменту кода не ясно, какой вообще контекст имеет `this`

Comment: вероятно, замена `$(this)` на `$("a.sl_item.active")` решит ваш вопрос. но опять таки не зная контекста, сложно что-либо рекомендовать.

Comment: Есть блок с слайдером, и есть блок с табами( блоки с id). В слайдере, итемы - это ссылки у которых в href = #id-таба.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вам нужно что-то в таком духе.

```
$('a.sl_item').on('click',function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#'+id).addClass('tab_active').siblings('.tab_active:first').removeClass('tab_active');
});
```